# Import database from sql file

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm beginner in sql. I have a question, how can I import the database from sql file. I tried option "import a script file" but it doesn't work. I attach a screenshots and my sql file

[screenshot](http://i41.tinypic.com/ac61c3.jpg)

[sql file](http://pastebin.com/zNzUbPZn)

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, you will need:

```
A .sql script file containing a CREATE TABLE command
MySQL Query Browser or phpMyAdmin
Other MySQL database tools will require similar steps.
An empty MySQL database already created
```

MySQL Query Browser is part of the MySQL GUI Tools available at
http://mysql.com/. These same steps can be used for most other MySQL administrator tools.

```
Using the MySQL Query Browser, connect to your MySQL Server.
From the Schemata panel, select the database you intend to add the new database table to.
Choose File > Open Script.
Navigate to the .sql file you wish to import.
Click Open.
Select Execute.
Confirm that the new database table appears in the Schemata panel.
```

Comment: I created new schema and i tried to run this script but there are an error in already first line: "unknown table" like on screenshot

Comment: the first error message says that there s no database selected, can you please double check it.

Comment: mysql query browser helped me, it runs

Comment: if it helped can you vote up and mark as answer so that it will be helpful for someone in the future.

Comment: why smallint[] is bad command? how can i declare array of smallint?     why "copy klienci from stdin null ''" didnt work too? under this there are a lot of data like this "1 Hłasko Regina Edwarda Bera 5 Elbląg 91-001 111222111"

Answer (score 2):

Just open a terminal,

login to mysql

use database,

source file/to/dump.sql

Comment: Very cool way to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Command line for this.

```
Shell> mysql -u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] dbname < sqlScript.sql
```

Comment: look an error:  http://i43.tinypic.com/2ihusyc.jpg                                  what should i type as a dbname when i havent any database?   In the classes we had finished and installed Linux and this base worked