# How to restore specific table from previous backup in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'am a beginner in mysql.
I accidentally deleted some row from a specific table in mysql for which I have luckily kept backup in .sql file,  So now how can I restore those deleted row of specific table in mysql, im using MySQL Administrator and Query browser to access database and database is install in a seperate ubuntu server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mYou can find in this post the inforation you need to import your **.sql** file

```
Using the MySQL Query Browser, connect to your MySQL Server.
From the Schemata panel, select the database you intend to add the new database table to.
Choose File > Open Script.
Navigate to the .sql file you wish to import.
Click Open.
Select Execute.
Confirm that the new database table appears in the Schemata panel.
```

THis is an old post on stackoverflow: [Import database from sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592497/import-database-from-sql-file)

I hope this will help you!